# Javascript store outputs and download file

Tags: javascript, download, storage

I have a JavaScript app that calculates various values. I would like to have a function that stores calculated output values (e.g. when you click a "store value" button), creating a list in the background that the user could then download as, e.g., a text file. I'm wondering what the easiest implementation of this would be in the browser -- values can get wiped on page refresh so no need to store long-term. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for a way to download a file with these values?

Here is a quick example of how to do that:

Let's say I have an a-tag in my html like this

```
<a id="Button" download="download.txt">Download</a>
```

I can then use javascript to make it download a file with text in it

```
Button = document.getElementById('Button');
theText="Hello";

var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    // returns a URL you can use as a href
    return textFile;
  };
Button.href=makeTextFile(theText);
```

Then when we click the link, it downloads a text file with the contents "Hello". I got this code from somewhere a really long time ago when I was working on a project, but I don't remember where it is from.

If this isn't what you are asking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes that seems to be on the right track. 
Basically I am pushing values into an array and am looking for a way to download the array data in a text file when desired. This seems like something I could work with; am playing around with it now.

Comment: @ThomasNicholson You could probably convert the array into a string somehow.

Comment: @ThomasNicholson you could use some thing like
`var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var x = fruits.toString();`
It would return a string of the values separated by commas.

Comment: I tried making a simplified version using "blob" but keep running into the same issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/afpvkyrg/

It seems `arrayText` is not understood for whatever reason. But if I replace it with something like `'test text'`, it _is_ understood. 

This is just a little Fiddle where you can type in values, push them into the array, and check that they are in there. Ideally, I could then download it.

Comment: @ThomasNicholson Use this as the javascript:
`var array = [];
var arrayText = "";
var blob;

function push() {
 array.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
 arrayText = array.toString();
  blob = new Blob([arrayText], {type: 'text/plain'});
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}`
The problem is that you weren't updating the link or the blob at all. I tested it, and it works.

Comment: glorious, thanks for catching that silly oversight. I can work with this! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any thoughts on how the user might be able to change the filename using, say, an input box (aside from just manually renaming the file after downloading).

Comment: @ThomasNicholson you can use `link.download = "whatever.something"`, so you can get the value of an input box and set `link.download` to that. The files don't even have to have a filetype if you want.